# What is best for performance: Array with keys or keys containing array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I am not sure what json structure is best performance based.

My structure currently looks like this:

```
{
    "walk": [
        {"x": 15,"y": 22,"on": ["onactive"]},
        {"x": 15,"y": 22,"on": ["onactive","agreeConditions"]}
    ]
}
```

This will basically repeat the key in each array object. Which will take up space.

In javascript you can loop through it like this:

```
for(var i = 0; i< walk.length; i++){
    console.log(walk[i].x);
    console.log(walk[i].y);
    console.log(walk[i].on);
}
```

What I am planning to restructure it to:

```
{
    "walk": {
        "x": [15,15],
        "y": [22,22],
        "on": [
            ["onactive"],
            ["onactive","agreeConditions"]
        ]
    }
}
```

This will be just 1 object containing all the keys and for each key it contains an array. Definitely takes up less space!

In javascript you can loop through it like this:

```
for(var i = 0; i< walk.x.length; i++){
    console.log(walk.x[i]);
    console.log(walk.y[i]);
    console.log(walk.on[i]);
}
```

The difference basically is an array containing keys and keys containing arrays.

So what will be performance based an good json structure?

array(

key:value,key:value

)

Or

object(

key:array(value,value)

)

Comment: How does the code know to associate the first array in the `on` list with "x" instead of "y"?  If you explicitly maintain the ordering, it'll work, but note that there's no guaranteed ordering of object properties when you iterate with `for ... in` (not that you're doing that here).

Comment: @Pointy I think the first array in the `on` list is associated with the first element of `x` and the first element of `y`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to know which one is faster, you can run your own benchmark tests. There should be almost no difference between the two, though.

I tend to prefer the first structure because it is easier to understand, and it allows you to pass the object as a parameter if you ever need to. For example, I can write a function:

```
function shiftWalkPoint(walkPoint, n) {
    walkPoint.x += n;
    walkPoint.y += n;
}

for (var i = 0; i < walk.length; i++){
    shiftWalkPoint(walk[i], 5);
}
```

However, with your second format, you cannot do that. You would have to pass the entire `walk` object as well as the index to any function that wants to use it, which is more awkward. You could also run into problems if something bad happens to your data and `x.length != y.length`.

Answer (score 1):

You can see from the JSON format that the only size difference in the textual format is the repeated property names in the array of objects. You can also see that it's easier to see which values belong together in the array of objects.

Looking at the way that you access the structures, there is no performance difference. Accessing the array of objects you use `walk[i].x`, which is equivalent to `walk[i][x]`. Accessing the object containing arrays you use `walk.x[i]`, which is equivalent to `walk[x][i]`. The only difference is the order of the accesses, which doesn't affect the performance.

Looking at the memory usage, the difference is very small. An array like `[15,15]` is represented in memory as an object where the items are properties with numerical keys, basically the same as `{ "length": 2, "0": 15, "1": 15 }`. That makes objects and arrays practically the same in terms of memory usage.

In conclusion:

- An object containing arrays is slightly more compact in text form (JSON).
- An array containing objects is a bit easier to read.
- There is no performance difference in accessing them.
- They will take up about the same amount of memory.

Comment: I agree that the performance difference is probably completely ignorable unless it's a massive structure (in which case something else is probably wrong), but I suspect modern JS runtimes treat array numeric-indexed properties specially when they can and avoid explicitly storing the "keys".

Comment: @Pointy: Yes, some browsers does optimise array access (http://jsperf.com/array-access-performance), but that doesn't make any difference. We are comparing one array access and one object access against one object access and one array access, and doing one before the other doesn't change the performance.

Comment: yes that's definitely true. Anyway I agree with Erlang's Joe Armstrong who says that programmers should just write the most beautiful programs they can, and leave the micro-optimization up to the platform people. (And that algorithmic optimization is what really matters :)